# JobRunr Spring Boot: how to get notified if a recurring job - including retries - has failed

Tags: spring-boot, jobrunr

I'm using jobrunr `5.1.4` in my spring boot application. I have a simple service declaring a recurring job which allows for some retries. A single failing job run is not that relevant for me. Instead, I'm interested in getting notified after all jobs, i.e. the initial job including all the retries, have failed.

I thought JobRunr's `JobServerFilter` would be a good idea. But the `onProcessed()` method never gets triggered in case of an exception only in case of a successful job run. And the `ApplyStateFilter` gets triggered on every state change. Far too often for my requirement. Leaving me clueless, if a change to a `FAILED` state was the last in a series of jobs belonging together (initial job + allowed retried jobs).

A simple example would look like this:

```
@Service
public class JobScheduler {

  @Job(name = "My Recurring Job", retries = 2, jobFilters = ExceptionFilter.class)
  @Recurring(id = "my-recurring-job", cron = "*/10 * * * *")
  public void recurringJob() {
    throw new RuntimeException("foo");
  }
}
```

A basic implementation of my `JobFilter` looks like this:

```
@Component
public class ExceptionFilter implements JobServerFilter, ApplyStateFilter {

  @Override
  public void onProcessing(Job job) {
    log.info("onProcessing: {}", job.getJobName());
    log.info(job.getJobState().getName().name());
  }

  @Override
  public void onProcessed(Job job) {
    log.info("onProcessed: {}", job.getJobName());
    log.info(job.getJobState().getName().name());
  }

  @Override
  public void onStateApplied(Job job, JobState jobState1, JobState jobState2) {
    log.info("onStateApplied: {}", job.getJobName());
    log.info("jobState1: {}", jobState1.getName().name());
    log.info("jobState2: {}", jobState2.getName().name());
  }
}
```

Is this use case even possible with JobRunr? Or does anyone have an idea how to solve this issue in a different way?

Thank you very much in advance for you support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're on the right track with `onStateApplied` from `ApplyStateFilter`.

You can use the following approach:

```java
  @Override
  public void onStateApplied(Job job, JobState oldState, JobState newState) {
    if (isFailed(newState) && maxAmountOfRetriesReached(job)) {
      // your logic here
    }
  }
```

`OnProcessed` is not triggered as your job was not processed (due to the failure).

Comment: Thank you @rdehuyss for your answer. This indeed helped me to solve my problem. Furthermore, the internals of JobRunr's [RetryFilter](https://github.com/jobrunr/jobrunr/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/jobrunr/jobs/filters/RetryFilter.java) gave me an idea on how to check if the max amount of retries have been reached.