# How to inject dependencies in a class implementing Jobrunr ApplyStateFilter interface?

Tags: java, spring-boot, autowired, jobrunr

I am trying to implement a project using jobrunr. I have a use case where a service I have written should be triggered once the maximum retries are done for a job. I tried achieving the same using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72950953/jobrunr-spring-boot-how-to-get-notified-if-a-recurring-job-including-retries) as reference. The filter logic is triggered once a job fails but the dependency I include (which has my logic) is returning a null point exception(java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.project.service.ScheduleHistoryService.someFunc()" because "this.service" is null). I am able to inject the same service file using @Autowire in my other components.
What am I doing wrong here?
I am using jobrunr version 5.1.4.
Attached is a screenshot of the sample code:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afr8F.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Injecting services in the filters is only possible in the Pro version of JobRunr.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but in the docs, they mentioned something like this, "A Job Filter can be used to extend the functionality of JobRunr with extra business processes when a job succeeds or fails. They also exist in the free version but in the Pro". 

Do they have any hacks for implementing it?

https://www.jobrunr.io/en/documentation/pro/job-filters/

Comment: I mean "Do they have any hacks for implementing it in the Free version?"

Comment: I don't like to create hacks :-)

Comment: @rdehyuss Is the point of JobFilter in the free version is just to do non-business stuff like logging?

Answer (score 0):

My hack / workaround for this is injecting the Service in the regarding Configuration and passing it to the constructor of a CustomRetryFilter:

```
@Configuration
public class JobRunrConfig {

    @Bean
    public BackgroundJobServer backgroundJobServer(
        StorageProvider storageProvider, JsonMapper jobRunrJsonMapper, JobActivator jobActivator, BackgroundJobServerConfiguration backgroundJobServerConfiguration, JobRunrProperties properties,
        ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher) {

    BackgroundJobServer backgroundJobServer = new BackgroundJobServer(
        storageProvider, jobRunrJsonMapper, jobActivator, backgroundJobServerConfiguration);
    backgroundJobServer.setJobFilters(
        Collections.singletonList(
            new CustomRetryFilter(
                applicationEventPublisher,
                properties.getJobs().getDefaultNumberOfRetries(),
                properties.getJobs().getRetryBackOffTimeSeed())));
    backgroundJobServer.start();
    return backgroundJobServer;
  }
}
```